# How to consider words with the same content as one word in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list similar to the one below and I want to consider words with the same content as one word. Is there a way to do this more effectively?

```
list 1 = ['data mining', 'datamining', 'data science', 'graph model']

list 2 = ['data mining', 'data mining', 'data mining', 'graph model']


list 2 = [item.replace('datamining', 'data mining') for item in  list 1]
list 2 = [item.replace('data science', 'data mining') for item in  list 1]
```

Comment: and once you have this done, what do you do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping of words to their canonical replacement, for example

```
d = {
    'datamining': 'data mining',
    'data science': 'data mining',
}
```

Then replace each word in `list1` with its canonical replacement; unmapped words are replaced with themselves.

```
list2 = [d.get(k, k) for k in list1]
```